# C++ Multicasting while connected through Mobile Hotspot device

Tags: c++, networking, multicast, hotspot

I'm new to network programming in C++ and I'm writing a very simple app that is suppose to do a multicast.

From my research I see one of the first things I need to do is find out if my router supports multicast forwarding and multicast routing protocols.

My point of confusion is, I am connected to the internet via a mobile hotspot device, and I don't exactly know how to find out if it supports multicasting.

Does anyone know how I can go about finding out if I can indeed send multicasts with this type of wireless connection?

Comment: Multicasts will need others to join it (see [IGMP protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol)), what do you want to achieve, streaming live stuff from your device?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to publish market data from a server app to a gui app via multicast. So the gui will listen on the IP that the server is publishing on. I'm just trying to find out what I need to do to see if I am even able to publish multicasts on the network i'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that on a linux box (that supports ifconfig) you can use the ifconfig command to see if multicast is supported.  eth0 for example will show Multicast along with some other information.

For windows in the command line:

```
netsh interface ip show joins
```

should tell you